# App not showing in 'open-in' menu when sharing URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a swift app that I want to receive URLs when shared from safari. However my app is not showing in the 'open-in' menu. Can anyone assist please?

So far I have the following Document Type
[image]

And have implemented the following in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print(url)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Is this an iOS 13 app? I mean, did you create the project in Xcode 11?

Comment: Yes iOS 13 and Xcode 11

Comment: Then the app delegate is irrelevant. The code now goes in the scene delegate. — But that doesn’t explain why you don’t appear in the Share sheet.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the tip. I'll look into that.